# Python list: the usuage of [:]

Tags: python, list, contextmanager

When I read the chapter 5 of the book *Python Essential Reference*, I have met some problem in the example *ListTransaction*. Here is the original code:

```
 class ListTransaction(object):
        def __init__(self,thelist):
            self.thelist=thelist
        def __enter__(self):
            self.workingcopy=list(self.thelist)
            return self.workingcopy
        def __exit__(self,type,value,tb):
            if type is None:
                self.thelist[:]=self.workingcopy
            return False


items=[1,2,3]
with ListTransaction(items) as working:
    working.append(4)
    working.append(5)
print(items) #[1,2,3,4,5]
```

It works as expected. But if I omit the `[:]` in the definition of `__exit__()`, that is, the 9th line becomes

```
 self.thelist=self.workingcopy
```

then the output will be

```
[1,2,3].
```

So what's the difference between the presence and absence of ***`[:]`*** after a list?

Comment: Assigning to a slice of a list mutates the list.

Comment: Thanks. But why `self.thelist=self.workingcopy` cannot change the contents of `self.thelist`?

Comment: `self.workingcopy` points to a list. If you set `self.list = self.workingcopy`, it just makes it point to a new list instead of *changing* the list it points to.